# mongoose: Find the biggest time difference between date entries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo db and use mongoose.  Is it possible to find the largest gap between dates?  So if I have:

```
LastUpdate: 2017-09-25 12:30:41.814Z
LastUpdate: 2017-09-25 12:31:41.814Z
LastUpdate: 2017-09-25 12:35:41.814Z
LastUpdate: 2017-09-25 12:36:41.814Z
LastUpdate: 2017-09-25 12:37:41.814Z
LastUpdate: 2017-09-25 12:39:41.814Z
```

It would return:

```
LastUpdate: 2017-09-25 12:31:41.814Z
LastUpdate: 2017-09-25 12:35:41.814Z
```

or even better, the middle point between the dates:

```
LastUpdate: 2017-09-25 12:33:41.814Z
```

I have an app that runs some code every so often.  I want to space out the requests (it runs for each user each day) so that they run as far apart from each other as possible.  I might be totally looking at this issue the wrong way so if you have a better solution, let me know.

Comment: Surely it is possible. Fetch all records ordered by LastUpdate and calculate gaps by iterating through the result.

Comment: @AlexBlex that was my fallback plan but I was hoping there was some fancy query I could do to save me some processing time.

Comment: I have posted an example how it could be possible done, but it hardly save you anything. See the comments in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to do so with a "fancy query" below, I'd recommend to calculate gaps on application level to "save some processing time".

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { $sort: {LastUpdate: 1} },
  // doubles the dataset
  { $facet: { 
      "first": [{ $match: {LastUpdate:{$exists: true}}}],
      "second": [{ $match: {LastUpdate:{$exists: true}}}]
  }}, 
  // squares it
  { $unwind: { 
      path: "$second",
      includeArrayIndex: "_num"
  }},
  { $match: { _num : {$gt: 0}}},
  // returns back to the doubled size
  { $project: { first: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$first", {$subtract: ["$_num", 1 ]}] }, second: 1}},
  // calculates the gap
  { $project: {
      first: 1,
      second: 1,
      gap: { $subtract: [ "$second.LastUpdate", "$first.LastUpdate" ] }
  }}, 
  { $sort: {gap: -1}}, 
  { $limit: 1}
])
```